# Setting Up the Feedly Refresh Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, feedly

I have successfully set up the [feedly developer access](https://developer.feedly.com/) token using the javascript library Axios on a NuxtJS site.  I am having trouble, though, figuring out how to set up the refresh token.

This is the process I have used for the developer token

```
export default function({ $axios }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = [FEEDLY_ACCESS_TOKEN]
  })
}
```

This code gets run whenever I make the relevant axios request.

What I am wondering, now, is what I need to do for the refresh token.  I have taken a look at the instructions on these two pages:

- https://developer.feedly.com/v3/developer/#what-happens-once-the-developer-access-token-expires
- https://developer.feedly.com/v3/auth/#refreshing-an-access-token

However, I'm still not 100% clear as to what I am supposed to do.  In particular, I have two questions:

1. Do I also run the refresh token each time I make an axios call -- or should I create a function that runs every thirty days and runs the code.
2. How exactly do I make the axios call for the refresh token.  My initial guess is something like this:

```
$axios.$post('https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/auth/token/?refresh_token=FEEDLY_REFRESH_TOKEN&client_id=feedlydev&client_secret=feedlydev&grant_type=refresh_token')
```

Is that correct?  If not, what do I need to change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Different developers will use different strategie regarding refreshing an access token. While some will return a new token on every request, other will do it over a term of days or longer.
The idea is to reduce the window of risk in which an access token can be abused but it is sort of a subjective topic imo. Obviously there is a performance penalty when you generate a new access token on every request. Sometimes this may be acceptable, but I really don't think it's necessary in many cases. Measure the tradeoff between the penalty and the sensitivity of the token in your case.

The docs explain it well:

Endpoint:

```
POST /v3/auth/token
```

It does say that using url parameters is not recommended, so why not just do it the way they recommend it? Either:

- using a x-www-form-urlencoded POST request (standard)
- as a JSON object (make sure you set the Content-Type header to “application/json”)

You have more questions around this?